# how to change ul width in carousels.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a client slider. How do I change client slider scrolling width.
I want to set the `<ul>` `width` to `980px`

Here's my current css code:

```js
var $clientcarousel = $('#clients-list');
var clients = $clientcarousel.children().length;
var clientwidth = (clients * 140); // 140px width for each client item 
$clientcarousel.css('width', clientwidth);

var rotating = true;
var clientspeed = 1800;
var seeclients = setInterval(rotateClients, clientspeed);

$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    rotating = false; // turn off rotation when hovering
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    rotating = true;
  }
}, '#clients');

function rotateClients() {
if (rotating != false) {
  var $first = $('#clients-list li:first');
  $first.animate({
    'margin-left': '-140px'
  }, 600, function() {
    $first.remove().css({
      'margin-left': '0px'
    });
    $('#clients-list li:last').after($first);
  });
}
}
});
```

```css
#clients {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#clients .clients-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#clients .clients-wrap ul {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
#clients .clients-wrap ul li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  text-align: center;
}
#clients .clients-wrap ul li img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  opacity: 0.65;
}
#clients .clients-wrap ul li img:hover {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clients">
  <h3>Past &amp; Present Clients</h3>
  <div class="clients-wrap">
    <ul id="clients-list" class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <img src="images/client01-cartoon-network.png" alt="Cartoon Network">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/client02-rough-draft-studios.png" alt="Rough Draft Studios">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/client03-spongebob-movie2.png" alt="SpongeBob Movie #2">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/client04-apple-inc.png" alt="Apple Computers">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/client05-google-talk.png" alt="Google chat talk">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/client06-g4tv.png" alt="G4TV channel">
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/client07-wonka-candy.png" alt="Wonka Chocolates and Candy">
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- @end .clients-wrap -->
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what your css looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width` to your value:

```
#clients .clients-wrap {
    display: block;
    width: 980px;   /* change this */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your un-ordered list `<ul>` is a child of the `.client-wrap` div, so it can only occupy a max width of it's parent width (the `.client-wrap` div).

Currently the parent width is 700px so it won't go larger than this unless you change the `width` value for `.client-wrap` to either 980px or more.

Try this to fix your problem:

```
#clients .clients-wrap {
    display: block;
    width: 980px;   /* change this */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```